# What Should I Bring To My First RPG?

Tags: new-players, roleplaying, star-wars

So, I'm playing my first tabletop with other people this weekend, and I have no idea what I need to prepare or bring with me.

It's an event for newbs like me at a local store (it's a Star Wars RPG if that helps) and seeing as I've never actually played in a group with other people before, I was wondering what I'd need to bring with me or if I need anything prepared.

Backstory: I went in there asking about how to get involved with D&D, bought the starter set and was invited to a couple of events, one being the Star Wars this weekend and one being D&D at the end of January. I know the D&D is for new guys too, using pregenerated characters, but I don't have any information on the Star Wars one - whether we're using pre-gen characters, starting a new campaign or joining one of their regular groups.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What materials should a new player bring to a gaming group](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/53842/what-materials-should-a-new-player-bring-to-a-gaming-group)

Comment: I think the system specific nature of this question makes it sufficiently different for it not to be a duplicate. This especially the case given the special dice required for the game the questioner is going to be playing and how difficult these would be to get

Comment: Bring pizza, lots of pizza.

Comment: I don't think it's so much the system-specificity of this question that makes it non-duplicate, as it is the "event for new players" angle.

Comment: For those interested, I bought a notepad, pencil, drink and snacks but I only actually needed a pencil - everyone got their own lunch halfway through. But all in all it was absolutely awesome and I've signed up for the next one!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

*Generally speaking, when you go to role-playing game, you should have at least some blank paper and a pencil.*

In your case, as this is a beginner event, they will very likely be providing the books and dice, and pre-printed character sheets, if any.  However, do not expect them to provide a writing instrument for you, and this is quite vital.

In any game other than Star Wars (Fantasy Flight Games), you might be expected or encouraged to bring your own basic set of polyhedral dice.  Anecdotally, demonstrations at one of my Friendly Local Game Stores would not provide dice, and would advise new players to go to the main room and purchase a Chessex set.

However, this being a Star Wars event, you can expect them to provide the dice, as the game uses special dice that no one has.  (Also, at time of writing, the dice are expensive, backordered from the manufacturer, and generally hard to come by, so if they expect to teach players the game, they would have to provide them.)

You should not be expected to have the book for an introduction or demo.  Keep in mind, the store is running this event partly to encourage you to buy the product, so already having the product would be counter productive.

If the demonstrator/instructor is kind, they may provide blank paper for notes and writing instruments, but do not count on it.  You should always have something to write with and write on.

If you want snacks or drinks, you should bring your own (unless the game store sells some, in which case, purchase your snacks from your game store).  Do not expect the demonstrator to provide them, or the other players to share.  That said, bring extra and share if you can manage it.

Comment: Normally, I would not include timely information in an answer - however the querent is asking a timely question.

Comment: +1 game stores don't generally give you dice they sell them, with Star Wars intro events definitely being a likely exception.

Comment: @mxyzplk while i give an anecdote to the contrary, I have been to demonstrations that were straight "Bring nothing", and the dm had dice to use that day.

Answer (score 8):

Bring a pencil, a sharpener (unless yours is a mechanical pencil), a rubber eraser and a small notepad.

Since you will be part of a pregenerated event and you're new to the game, I expect the organizers to provide the character sheet, the dice (but if you have your own set, bring it!) and the rules.
You will find that sometimes writing notes is important for the game and sometimes you will need to change numbers on your sheet pretty frequently (the number of hit points your D&D character has is pretty dynamic) - frequently writing and erasing the same spot on a character sheet is a recipe for disaster, use your noteblock instead.

Comment: If they want to bring dice, it will be a long wait - the dice the game uses are on a slow moving boat from China to the distributor.  (as of December 30th 2015)

Comment: You can borrow dice from the GM or experienced players, and they should have a pregenerated character sheet, but it'll never do any harm to have a pencil, some blank paper, and an eraser.  Snacks are also very good (within the rules of the hosting shop, of course).

Answer (score 5):

As this is an event to get new people into the hobby, you should not need to bring anything. They will provide anything you need (which basically is only dice, paper, pencils and the rulebooks).

Be there 10 minutes early, so you can ask and if you do indeed need something, you can buy it there.

If you want to make friends fast, bring a bag of snacks. Something that's tasty, but does not leave stains in or on the books. So for example cookies are fine, ice cream tends to get messy as does chocolate when it's warm.

Answer (score 1):

You've been invited to a beginner's event.  Don't plan on bringing anything to the game table.  You should consider what you might want to spend on purchases after the game, assuming you've enjoyed the experience.

I've run this sort of event and the only thing I want the players to bring is a desire to learn and have fun.  Expect Pre-Gen characters, accept that they might not be a perfect fit.  Try something new, this is a great chance to play with the rules.

Most importantly, have fun!

Answer (score 0):

As some others have answered, it would be beneficial to you and others if you bring your own pencils and paper. I would avoid pens as most RPG's will require alot of erasing since many things change during a game. You can get dice there if you need it, but every game may require a different set or number of dice, so until you know for sure what you'll need, I wouldnt worry about bringing those the day of the game.

Snacks and drink are good(if the shop allows food and drink inside, some dont), especially if you want to avoid locating food during the game, not everyone takes lunch or food breaks, especially if the event is only for a couple of hours.

Lastly, make sure you bring your imagination, THAT is what playing these games is all about really. For the first event, bring your general knowledge of the Star Wars universe(if you have any) so you can take advantage of the most material.  If you know nothing about Star Wars, thats fine, but if you do, that knowledge can help you figure out what character to play(or make should they be doing that) and can help you with questions like "what do i do now?" Your in the star wars universe, if your playing a smuggler or Han Solo type, what would Han do now? That can help you get past some of the starter struggles of feeling like you dont know "how" to play.

Always remember the #1 rule....HAVE FUN!!

Good Gaming.

Answer (score 0):

A set of RP dice, a notepad, something to write with, coke, funyuns, some rope and a ten foot pole.

Comment: I get the joke... But really, is it really a good idea to bring 50' of rope and a 10' poll to a game shop?

Comment: I don't mind taking the karma hit for once - Have a great new year's eve everyone! ;)

Comment: Knowing the guys in the shop, they'd probably lean more towards hilarity so this answer is by far the most accurate haha!